# Parsing WML on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, wml

I have a WML based source of data which I need to parse in an iPhone app.

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

I'm currently looking into the various XML libraries available on the iPhone but would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Currently playing around with ElementParser, it seems that WML isn't close enough to XML as I'd hoped..

Comment: You might find this question useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281388/when-parsing-with-nsxmlparser-does-it-download-the-whole-xml-then-parse-or-doe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the data going to be used for? If you want to be able to display a web page on the iPhone you might want to try running an XSLT over the WML to produce standard HTML that can be displayed easily (assuming your WML is valid XML).

The best library for doing this would probably be [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/) as the native iPhone libraries seem to be lacking in this area.

Comment: The WML comes from a WAP site, the data contained on each page needs to be stripped out and stored for use in tablecells. Navigation entries need to be stripped and stored for background data retrieval.

Comment: Have you had any luck with using the library I mentioned in my answer? If the format of the WML pages is fairly standard then the process of extracting the data you need should be trivial.